# Looking for a query with a subquery

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables in my database:

- `TableA` contains `aId`, `aBId`, `a3`, ...
- `TableB` contains `bId`, `b2value`, `b3`,...

`aBId` is a the `bId` of the `tableB`.

I need a mysql query that selects all the records from tableA where the record from bId has b2value = 'something'...
hate queries...

Comment: [INNER JOIN](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx) mentioning answers incoming in 3... 2...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select a.* 
from TableA a
inner join TableB b on a.aBid = b.bId
where b.b2Value = 'something'
```

Answer (score 0):

> select a.* from TableA a join TableB b on a.aBId = b.bId where
>   b.b2value = 'something'

Answer (score 0):

```
    select * 
    from TableA
    inner join TableB on TableA.aBId = TableB.bId
    where TableB.b2Value = 'something'
```